# Can we get the exact location where the condition fails, in an If case having multiple conditions?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to Java,
Here is my code,

```
if(   a.name == b.name 
      && a.displayname == b.displayname
      && a.linkname == b.linkname
      .........   )
return true;
else
return false;
```

I will call this method and have to check that all properties of objects 'a' and 'b'.
Each object will have more than 20 properties. So, it is will be tidy if i use if case for each property.

An exception is throwed if the return is false and I have to report which property fails.
Is there any easy method to find where the condition fails within the if case.

Pls help. Ask if you are not clear about the question.

Comment: use '.equals' instead of '==' for string comparison

Comment: Do you mean with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use reflection: browse what fields are defined, and check each of them using method equals. Print error message if they're not equal, give summary at the end.

```
boolean equals = true;
Field[] fields = a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f: fields){
    f.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            if (!f.get(a).equals(f.get(b))){
                System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + f.get(a) + "!="+ f.get(b));
                equals = false;
            };
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
System.out.println("equals?: " + equals);
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is, would you like to continue checking if one of the conditions fails?
You could do something like comparator where you have interface:

```
public interface IComparator {
    boolean compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2);
    String getComparatorName();
}
```

Next you create set of implementations of that interface:

```
NameComparator implements IComparator {

    private name="Name Comparator";

    @Override
    public boolean compare(YourObject o1, YourObjecto2) {
        return o1.getName().equals(o2.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public String getComparatorName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Next you store set of these comparators in arrayList and you iterate through them and record which one fails by adding them to some other collection.. Hope that helps!

For instance you create array:

```
IComparator[] comparators = new IComparator[]{ new NameComparator, new DisplayNameComparator};

List<IComparator> failedComparationOperations = new ArrayList<IComparator>();

for(IComparator currentComparator : comparators)  {
    if(!currentComparator.compare(o1, o2)) {
        failedComparationOperations.add(currentComparator);
    }
}

for(IComparator currentComparator: failedComparationOperations)
{
    System.out.println("Failed Comparation at: "+currentComparator.getComparatorName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know which of the conditions has failed you should check each of the conditions independently.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little overkill if you are dealing with this single requirement, but what about the Strategy Design Pattern?
http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

It should be an interesting option if you have other business rules that you can combine with this check.

Answer (score 0):

Without reflection you can't get maximum conciseness, but the followincg can help you to some extent. Make this kind of class:

```
class NamedEquals {
   final String name;
   final Object left, right;
   NamedCondition(String name, Object left, Object right) { ...assign them... }
   boolean areEqual() { return left.equals(right); }
}
```

Then make a `List<NamedEquals>`:

```
List<NamedEquals> conds = Arrays.asList(
  new NamedEquals("name", left.name, right.name),
  new NamedEquals("displayname", left. displayname, right.displayname),
  ...
);
```

And you can find if some of them fail:

```
for (NamedEquals eq : conds) 
  if (!eq.areEqual()) throw new ValidationException(eq.name);
```

Using a factory method can shorten the construction code:

```
static NamedEquals eq(String name, Object left, Object right) {
   return new NamedEquals(name, left, right);
}
```

With that you can have

```
List<NamedEquals> conds = Arrays.asList(
  eq("name", left.name, right.name),
  eq("displayname", left. displayname, right.displayname),
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` are instances of the same class, let's assume `A`, and the fields are visible, then you can use reflections:

```
for (Field f : A.class.getFields()) {
    try {
        if (!f.get(a).equals(f.get(b))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Field " + f.getName() + " is different.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
    // Adapted from your example:
    if(!equalTo(a.name, b.name))
        fail("name");
    if(!equalTo(a.displayname, b.displayname))
        fail("displayname");
    ... etc ...

...

// Allow for null values.
public boolean equalTo(Object a, Object b) {
    return a != null ? a.equals(b) : b == null;
}

public void fail(String which) throws SomeException {
    throw new SomeException("Failed on '"+which+"'!");
}
```

Another possible might be to turn each object into a `Map<String,?>`, perhaps by adding a `Map<String,?> toMap()` method to the value object, and implementing this by constructing a new map and dumping the value's fields into it.  Then you can get the maps and do `equals()` on them.

Comment: BTW  If at all possible, I'd stay away from reflection.

Comment: I think simple classes working as "commands" for comparing would do the job